# Varnish cache - cannot handle 4000 concurrent users

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Experiencing the issue when loading ~ 4000 concurrent users on a WP site. 
Here is the configuration I have:

F5 loadbalancer ---> Varnish 4 with 8 cores, 32 Gb RAM ---> 9 backends with 4 cores, 16 RAM each, running WP site.

While the load is ~ 2500-3000 users all is going fine, without any errors, but when users reaching 4k, varnish stops responding until it compute all queued requests, plus we see many 502 errors.

Have 2 pools, 5000 threads each; malloc=30G

Additionaly added SOMAXCONN and TCP_MAX_SYN_Backlog into sysctl

Here is the VCL:

```
  vcl 4.0;
import directors;
import std;
backend qa2 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa3 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa4 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa5 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa6 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa7 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa8 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa9 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }
backend qa10 { .host = "xxx"; .port = "80"; }

# .connect_timeout = 2s; .first_byte_timeout = 10m; .between_bytes_timeout = 10m;

acl purge_list {
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
    "xxx";
}
sub vcl_init {
    new rr = directors.round_robin();
    rr.add_backend(qa2);
    rr.add_backend(qa3);
    rr.add_backend(qa4);
    rr.add_backend(qa5);
    rr.add_backend(qa6);
    rr.add_backend(qa7);
    rr.add_backend(qa8);
    rr.add_backend(qa9);
    rr.add_backend(qa10);
}

sub vcl_recv {
  set req.backend_hint = rr.backend();
 if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge_list) {
            return(synth(405, "not allowed."));
        }
        ban("req.url ~ .css");
        return(synth(200, "CSS Files Cleared from Cache!"));
  }
  # Don't check cache for POSTs and various other HTTP request types
  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    #ban("req.http.host == " + req.http.host);
    return(pass);

  }
  # Don't check cache for POSTs and various other HTTP request types
   if (req.http.Cookie ~ "SESS[a-f|0-9]+" || 
    req.http.Authorization || 
    req.url ~ "login" ||
    req.method == "POST" ||
    req.http.Cookie || 
    req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin)") {
    return (pass);
   }
  if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
          unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
      } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
          set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
      } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
          set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
      } else {
          unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
      }
  }

  if (req.url ~ "\.(aif|aiff|au|avi|bin|bmp|cab|carb|cct|cdf|class|css)$"  ||
      req.url ~ "\.(dcr|doc|dtd|eps|exe|flv|gcf|gff|gif|grv|hdml|hqx)$"    ||
      req.url ~ "\.(ico|ini|jpeg|jpg|js|mov|mp3|nc|pct|pdf|png|ppc|pws)$"  ||
      req.url ~ "\.(swa|swf|tif|txt|vbs|w32|wav|wbmp|wml|wmlc|wmls|wmlsc)$"||
      req.url ~ "\.(xml|xsd|xsl|zip|woff)($|\?)") {
      unset req.http.Cookie;
      #unset req.http.Authorization; 
      #unset req.http.Authenticate; 
      return (hash);
  }

  return(hash);
}

# Cache hit: the object was found in cache
sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        return (synth(200, "Purged!"));
    }
}
# Cache miss: request is about to be sent to the backend
sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        return (synth(200, "Purged (Not in cache)"));
    }
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
  if (bereq.url ~ "\.(aif|aiff|au|avi|bin|bmp|cab|carb|cct|cdf|class|css)$"  ||
      bereq.url ~ "\.(dcr|doc|dtd|eps|exe|flv|gcf|gff|gif|grv|hdml|hqx)$"    ||
      bereq.url ~ "\.(ico|ini|jpeg|jpg|js|mov|mp3|nc|pct|pdf|png|ppc|pws)$"  ||
      bereq.url ~ "\.(swa|swf|tif|txt|vbs|w32|wav|wbmp|wml|wmlc|wmls|wmlsc)$"||
      bereq.url ~ "\.(xml|xsd|xsl|zip|woff)($|\?)") {
    set beresp.grace = 30s;
    set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public, max-age=600";
    set beresp.http.expires = beresp.ttl;  
    return (deliver);
  }
}
# Deliver the response to the client
sub vcl_deliver {
  # Add an X-Cache diagnostic header
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    # Don't echo cached Set-Cookie headers
    unset resp.http.Set-Cookie;
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
  # Remove some headers not needed on production systems
  #  unset resp.http.Via;
  #  unset resp.http.X-Generator;
  #  return(deliver);
}*
```

And here are the results of last test:

[image]

[image]

Actually response time is good, but throughput is poor and as i already wrote, Varnish freezes until it finish resolving all previous requests.

So the questions are - is there a theoretical limit for varnish concurrent users? How can i tune it up to work with more than 4k concurrent connections?

PS. Also extended MaxClients on each of Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish will never produce a 502 return code, which means that you're most likely not caching responses.

You may very well be benchmarking your backend instead.

There are no built in limits on number of concurrent users. Your thread count looks fine. For only 4000 sessions you shouldn't need to do any kernel/OS tuning, the defaults should be fine. If you hit somaxconn, that is most likely an artifact of your benchmarking tools, and probably won't be the case on real traffic.

Summing up: Check the hit rates and look at varnishlog to figure out why things aren't being cached.

Comment: Yeah, sorry i didnt mention that the hitrate is just fine, more than 90% HIT, so Varnish is caching normally. Meanwhile, backends load is not more than 60-70 % on each machine, everything seems to be good. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

502 Bad Gateway means your backend is failing in some manner, and Varnish isn't able to connect, which is probably why its freezing up with a huge queue.

I notice here you're passing anything with a set cookie in vcl_recv:

```
  # Don't check cache for POSTs and various other HTTP request types
   if (req.http.Cookie ~ "SESS[a-f|0-9]+" || 
    req.http.Authorization || 
    req.url ~ "login" ||
    req.method == "POST" ||
*** req.http.Cookie || 
    req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin)") {
    return (pass);
   }
```

Especially with Wordpress this is going to kill your hitrate, and cause a ton of backend connections since varnish won't cache cookies.

Here's some sample code we use vcl_recv to handle cookies:

```
# Pass if the page is login, admin, preview, search or xmlrpc
if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin|json)" || req.url ~ "preview=true" || req.url ~ "\?s=" || req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php" || req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in_") {
    return (pass);
}

# Some wordpress URL manipulation
if (req.url ~ "\?(utm_(campaign|medium|source|term)|adParams|client|cx|eid|fbid|feed|ref(id|src)?|v(er|iew))=") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
}

# Some generic URL manipulation, useful for all templates that follow
# First remove the Google Analytics added parameters, useless for our backend
if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
}

# Strip hash, server doesn't need it.
if (req.url ~ "\#") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\#.*$", "");
}

# Strip a trailing ? if it exists
if (req.url ~ "\?$") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
}

# Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the wp test cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the cloudflare cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__cfduid=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the PHPSESSID in members area cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "PHPSESSID=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}

# Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages 
if (!(req.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|cart|my-account/*|checkout|addons|wordpress-social-login|wp-login\.php|forumPM|members|logout|lost-password|product/*)")) {
    unset req.http.cookie; 
}
```

This should be sufficient to add to vcl_backend_response:

```
# Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages 
if ( (!(bereq.url ~ "(wp-(login|admin)|login|cart|my-account/*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|product/*)")) ) { 
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it today.